# I want a function in R to check whether values of one column are greater than the 75th quantile then writes yes or no in the next column

Tags: r, function, if-statement, outliers, quantile

I have tried the following formula but it gives all nos even when I change the quantile value.
NOTE: I have 3 independent datasets that I want to apply the function.

```
outlier<-function(x1,x2){
  q1<-quantile(x1 , .75, na.rm = TRUE)
    if(x1>q1){x2<-"Yes"
    }else{
      x2<-"No"
    
  }

}
```

I have tried `x2<-ifelse(x1>q1,"Yes","No")`
inside the function but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `ifelse` statement and create a new column using `mutate`.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)

df <- tibble(x1 = sample(c(1:10), size = 10, replace = T))

df %>% 
  mutate(x2 = ifelse(quantile(x1, 0.75, na.rm = T) < x1, "Yes", "No"))
```

If you want a function

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)

df <- tibble(x1 = sample(c(1:10), size = 10, replace = T), 
             x2 = sample(c(1:10), size = 10, replace = T),
             x3 = sample(c(1:10), size = 10, replace = T),
             x4 = sample(c(1:10), size = 10, replace = T))




outlier<-function(dataframe, quant = 0.75, col = c("x1", "x2")){
  
  dataframe %>% 
    mutate(across(all_of(col), ~ifelse(.x>quantile(.x,0.75), 'Yes', 'No'),
                  .names = '{col}_yes'))

  }

outlier(dataframe = df,quant =  0.25)
```

Comment: Thank you. Although I want a function that I can apply to multiple columns where x1 and x2 are not the exact column names.

Comment: It may be interesting to `apply` the function to multiple columns instead of creating a function with a specific number of column arguments. It makes the function more flexible

Comment: If it is applied to mutiple columns, what kind ouf output do you want @Kemboi? One yes/no column for each column?

Comment: @KemboiIanKibet tumia `across`. Hakuna haja ya kutumia `apply`. Hii code umepewa hapa just update it to `...%>% mutate(across(all_of(your_selected_columns), ~ifelse(.x>quantile(.x,0.75), 'Yes', 'No'), .names = '{col}_yes'))`

Comment: @Julian, Yes. The suggestions should be in a such a way that I don't have to repeat the same code for several datasets and columns

Comment: @KU99 thank you, but I would love a reusable function

Comment: Just to clarify, The   `q1<-quantile(x1 , .75, na.rm = TRUE)` section works well when I define it outside the function but I want it within the function. Thank you

Comment: You can simply write a function `outlier <- function(x) ifelse(x > quantile(x, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE), 'Yes', 'No')`. The call the function inside `mutate`

Comment: I edited my answer with @KU99 suggestions.

Comment: Thank you @Julian. It worked pretty well

Comment: Thank You, everyone.  My problem is solved